# use regex to verify a text using a multiple if statements in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to identify the data/text being submitted from `<input>` if it contains any of the following. `youtube`, `vimeo`,`normal website`, `jpg/png`, `plain text`

```
if a youtube link is found {
    //do something
  } else if a vimeo link is found {
    //do something
  } else if a normal website is found {
    //do something
  } else if a (jpg/png) is found {
    //do something
  } else  just a text {
} //do something
```

---

as of the moment is my syntax. the youtube & vimeo regex format were taken from other posts. but im not sure how to create the proper regex for the others.

ive tried some regex generator but its so complicated to use

im also interested to know if this is the proper way of executing multiple conditional statement.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.submit', function () {
        var data = $('#input').val();
        var youtube = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
        var vimeo = /^(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(vimeo\.com\/)([0-9]+)$/;


        if (data.match(youtube)) {
            alert("utube");
        }
        else if (data.match(vimeo)) {
            alert("vimeo");
        }
            else if ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, some combination of `if` and `else` is the correct way to go about it. You need to nail down exact rules for what you want to match before you can come up with a regular expression for it, though; for example, what should "a normal website" cover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a switch statement when you have multiple regex conditions to check for:

```
var data = $('#input').val();
var youtube = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
var vimeo = /^(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(vimeo\.com\/)([0-9]+)$/;
var normalWebsite = /^(?:ftp|http|https):\/\/(?:[\w\.\-\+]+:{0,1}[\w\.\-\+]*@)?(?:[a-z0-9\-\.]+)(?::[0-9]+)?(?:\/|\/(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&%@!\-\/\(\)]+)|\?(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&%@!\-\/\(\)]+))?$/;
var image = /<img\s+src\s*=\s*(["'][^"']+["']|[^>]+)>/;

switch (true) {
  case youtube.test(data):
    alert('youtube');
    break;
  case vimeo.test(data):
    alert('vimeo');
    break;
  case normalWebsite.test(data):
    alert('normal website');
    break;
  case image.test(data):
    alert('image');
    break;
  default:
    // Here we are assuming anything that doesn't match the above is plain text.
    // You will need an additional regex if you want to make sure this doesn't contain html or code.
    alert('Plain text');
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a million different ways to do this.

The other regex you need are roughly bellow. Also it will save you a bit of a headache if you lowercase your data

```
var data = $("#input").val.toLowerCase();
```

**Web url**

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/
```

**PNG / JPG is at end of the string**

```
/(png|jpg|jpeg)$/
```

**Plain text i guese would be what ever is left**

The most efficient way is also to use a switch statement not a big if else

like this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

```
switch(n)
{
case 1:
  execute code block 1
  break;
case 2:
  execute code block 2
  break;
default:
  code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
```